# What's the etymology of "humdinger"?

Tags: etymology, american-english, slang, origin-unknown

A ***humdinger*** is a remarkable or outstanding person or thing.

The OED has it as originally US dating (as *hum-dinger*) from 1905, but says the origin is unknown.

Where does the word *humdinger* come from? Was it used before 1905?

Comment: "Anglicized versions of Irish expressions" http://www.nytimes.com/2007/11/08/nyregion/08irish.html?_r=0

Comment: @Susan: The "define dinger" Google result says *late 19th cent.: shortening of humdinger.*

Comment: @Susan: I did but the graph has no indication of OCR errors or other meanings. I clicked through to see some examples and they appeared to be OCR errors of "danger". Is there any evidence to suggest *humdinger* comes *dinger*, rather than the other way around, as Google's definition states? Or that this "outstanding" meaning of *dinger* is really around since before 1800?

Comment: @Susan: No problem! Who knows, perhaps it did exist with this meaning before 1800. OCR is "optical character recognition", or what computers do when they scan a page and try and recognise the printed letters and turn it into text. Sometimes they make mistakes, especially with older, less clear type. So a smudgy *a* in *danger* may be misattributed by the computer's OCR program as an *i* to create *dinger*.

Comment: @Susan: U.S. immigration records begin with 1820, so there isn't a reliable way of comparing immigration figures after that date with levels of immigration before then: not just for the Irish, but for any immigrant group. Most documented "Irish" immigration before the Potato Famine of the 1850s was Scots-Irish (mainly of Presbyterian background from Scotland, previously relocated to northern Ireland). It would be interesting to know whether "Irish expressions" refers to one of these groups or to both.

Comment: Just for the record: The etymological claims made by Mr. Cassidy in the NYT article linked to above are quite often demonstrably false. Most of them are folk etymology, often quite tenuous ones at that. His book and claims have become popular, but have been debunked time and time again by linguists and etymologists working with the Irish language.

Comment: The word was used by Character John Sims in the 1934 film "Our Daily Bread" to describe something that pleased him. I believe it's the first time I'd heard the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the entry for *humdinger* in Eric Partridge, *A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English* (1961):

> **humdinger.** A fast aircraft or vehicle; a smooth-running engine: Services, but mostly R.A.F.: adopted in mid-1940 from American airmen. American s[ource]: echoic: *hum* (speed) + *dinger* (something forceful).

Partridge published a dictionary of RAF slang in 1945, so he's especially knowledgeable about words used in that service.

Wentworth & Flexner, *Dictionary of American Slang* (1961) addresses the *dinger* part of the term in its entry for *humdinger*:

> **humdinger** *n.* Something or someone very remarkable or admirable. See **dinger**. *c1905: archaic and dial. now. adj.* Remarkable.

And here is part 1 of the *dinger* entry from that same source:

> **dinger** *n.* **1** Any remarkable person or thing. *Obs.* See **hum-dinger.** 1951: "President Truman used it not once, but twice, in characterizing a sermon he had heard. ... 'That was a dinger, chaplain,' said [he], and a moment later: 'I said it was a dinger.'"

Chapman & Kipfer, *Dictionary of American Slang*, Third Edition (1996) removes its predecessor's comment that *humdinger* is "archaic and dial. now," though it reasserts the "by 1905" coinage period. I can't help wondering if Bob Dylan's rhyme in "I Shall Be Free" ("She's a humdinger/Folk singer/Dead ringer/For a thingamajigger"), which came out in 1963, helped bring humdinger back into popular usage. The [Ngram Viewer graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=humdinger&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chumdinger%3B%2Cc0) for *humdinger* is not inconsistent with that possibility, though the relationship does seem rather far-fetched.

The third volume of the prodigious Farmer & Henley, *Slang and Its Analogues*, with alphabetical entries ranging from "Fla. to Hyps." was published in 1893 and has no entry for *humdinger*, so the term certainly wasn't in widespread use long before 1905.

A Google Books search, however, turns up [Roberts et al. v. Date et al.](http://books.google.com/books?id=xRo4AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA241&dq=%22humdinger%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1VXPUtmDPIn5oASDwIHYBw&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBDge#v=onepage&q=%22humdinger%22&f=false) (1903), a U.S. Circuit Court of Appeals decision involving interests in an Alaska mining claim called "the Humdinger" that had been filed by the defendants in the case on June 22, 1900. Other mining claims under dispute in the same case were called "the Marie," "the Discovery," and "the Eagle Canyon." The Humdinger claim was located on Slate creek, so "Humdinger" does not appear to be a place name (as opposed to a descriptive name).

Another early reference appears in the [Paint, Oil and Drug Review](http://books.google.com/books?id=ROc1AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA2-PA75&dq=%22humdinger%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9GbPUpvADYLroATAq4DwDg&ved=0CFwQ6AEwCDhk#v=onepage&q=%22humdinger%22&f=false) (February 6, 1907):

> A little incident that occurred in Indian Territory recently shows how the Indians are cheated. Some time since a well drilled by a Mr. "X" was reported as having been found to be dry. The rigging was removed, the derrick torn don,the hole capped and apparently the well was abandoned. A short time thereafter there appeared an advertisement offering for lease the 20 acres belonging to an Indian girl and adjoining the lease where Mr. "X" had found the "dry" hole. The lease was offered for sale by a master in chancery. It was sold for a cash bonus of $2,550, together with one-fourth royalty on all oil discovered. A representative of Mr. "X" was the purchaser. After the sale had been made to him Mr. "X" confided to a friend that the "dry" hole had not been quite so dry as reported. In fact, it was, in the parlance of the craft, a "humdinger."

Yet another early Google Books mention of *humdinger* comes from the records of the [Brown Swiss Cattle Breeders' Association](http://books.google.com/books?id=-45OAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA691&dq=%22humdinger%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=elXPUouUH8XzoATmvYKwCg&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22humdinger%22&f=false) (1908), which details the parenting exploits of a bull named Humdinger that lived in Illinois and sired 18 registered calves that were born between January 31, 1906, and November 19, 1907. Humdinger himself was born on December 5, 1903, and registered (#2187) at some unspecified time thereafter.

Comment: Thanks! It seems likely *humdinger* is from *dinger*. OED has *dinger* chronologically from 1809 and etymologically from the verb *ding*: "**3.** *fig.* To ‘beat’, overcome, surpass, excel." This is from [?a1513] or 1724.

Answer (score 0):

I found a *humdinger* earlier than the OED's 1905. I'll quote a large section as it gives the full context of why the "rhetorical humdinger" under discussion "is one of the architectural wonders of word construction".

*[The Butte Inter Mountain](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83025294/1902-01-27/ed-1/seq-4/#date1=1836&sort=date&date2=1905&searchType=advanced&language=&sequence=0&index=1&words=humdinger&proxdistance=5&rows=20&ortext=&proxtext=&phrasetext=humdinger&andtext=&dateFilterType=yearRange&page=1)*, January 27, 1902:

> REPRESENTATIVE SIBLEY'S SPEECH
>
> [Denver Republican.]
>
> If it were not for the fact that he is
>   from the staid and conservative Keystone
>   state, that has never encouraged
>   wind-jamming politicians, it might be
>   suspected that Representative Sibley
>   was trying to make himself popular by
>   using the brand of oratory that
>   stampeded the democratic national convention in 1896.
>
> When a man gets up in congress and
>   says that the present accomplishment
>   of irrigation will be "pressing a poisoned
>   chalice to the lips of the farming classes
>   of this nation," it is time for the people
>   to look out for another boy orator.
>
> But we fear that Mr. Sibley was so intent
>   on springing his "poisoned chalice"
>   smile on congress that he lost sight of
>   any such trifling thing as truth in his
>   speech. We admit that the metaphor,
>   epigram, or whatever Mr. Sibley choose
>   to call it, is one of the architectural
>   wonders of word construction.
>
> We have analyzed it from all sides --
>   full face, three-quarters and profile, and
>   we can find no laws in it from the stand-point
>   of the debating society. It is
>   rhetorical **humdinger** that will doubtless
>   be accepted as standard, and that will
>   figure in many a country schoolhouse
>   debate.

And [Stephen Goranson](http://listserv.linguistlist.org/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind1401B&L=ADS-L&D=0&P=32057&F=P) found a 19th century *humdinger*:

> In an ad for new cabs, of five levels of quality, the best being "A humdinger, only… [$]15.00"
>
> Paper: Daily Register Gazette, published as The Rockford Daily Register-Gazette.; Date: 04-07-1896; Page: 2; col. 7 Location: Rockford, Illinois. [Amer. Hist. News.]

---

As [Sven Yargs' answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/145409/9001) shows, it seems likely *humdinger* is from the earlier *dinger*:

> Any remarkable person or thing.

The OED has the noun *dinger* chronologically from 1809 and etymologically from the verb *ding*:

> "**3.** *fig.* To ‘beat’, overcome, surpass, excel."

This *ding* is from [?a1513] or 1724.

Comment: I've sent this antedating to the [OED](http://global.oup.com/uk/oedsubform/).

Comment: This is irrelevant to the discussion of _humdinger_, but I note that the _Denver Republican_'s comment about "boy orator" is an allusion to William Jennings Bryan (aka "the Boy Orator of the Platte [River, in Nebraska]," aka "the Great Commoner," aka "the Silver Knight of the West"), the Democratic nominee for President in 1896 and 1900 (he lost both times to the Republican William McKinley). Bryan is most famous for his opposition to the gold standard ("You shall not crucify mankind upon a cross of gold") and for his participation as an anti-evolution witness in the Scopes "monkey" trial.

Answer (score 0):

" Dinger " or "Ding" suggests bell ringing.  Does not the "winner"  ( of anything ) sometimes ring the bell or cause the bell to be rung ? Particularly in past days of circus or public gatherings.    How "hum" became attached to dinger...?   Some times something thrown or fired makes a humming noise in flight.  Therein lies a theory. Perhaps a winner at a gathering threw or fired accurately and hit the bell or the bell was rung when the target was hit by whatever was thrown or fired.   All supposition of course.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! As you suggest, this is theory or supposition, both of which are welcome and discussed liberally on this site. You might, however, want to transform your answer into a comment, just because comments on the site are more suited to opinion than answers are. The site's help center offers suggestions about writing answers for the site.